# database configuration for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie to Ruby on Rails.So can any one please tell me how to setup the database for it.I have MySQL installed which works for my php project.So is that good for Rails or should I install another mySQL.I have just installed rails and I am facing problems related to the database.From where I have to configure the database for my Rails project? I am using ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqladmin -u username -p create mydatabasename
```

then edit `config/database.yml` accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to create your database. Please take a look here for a detailed way to do it :

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

After creating your database(as seen in other answers), your config/database.yml file might look like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: site_development
  username: username
  password: password
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: site_test
  username: username
  password: password
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: site_production
  username: username
  password: password
  host: localhost
```